# How to convert in Expression Language (EL) double or float value to int without round-off?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, expression, el, jsp-tags

I am using Expression Language (EL) in JSP.

```
<c:set var="noOfPages" value="${numItems/itemsPerPage}" />

<fmt:formatNumber var="noOfPagesRounded" value="${noOfPages}" maxFractionDigits="0" />

<c:if  test="${(numItems % itemsPerPage) > 0}">
    <c:set var="noOfPages" value="${noOfPagesRounded + 1}"/>
</c:if >
```

As you see I am calculating no. of pages required to display `x` no. of results per page.

This doesn't work all time since at line 2 i.e. `formatNumber` tag is rounding of my division results, which I don't want to get rounded off.

i.e. for 73 records 20 per page needs 4 pages but I am getting result 5, because at line 2  it is rounding of result 3.65 to 4 but I want `noOfPagesRounded=3`.

How should I convert `float` or `double` value in `int` without rounding off?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want noOfPagesRounded to be set to floor(noOfPages) then try this (a floor function is not available in EL):

```
<fmt:formatNumber var="noOfPagesFloored" value="${noOfPages-(noOfPages%1)}"  maxFractionDigits="0" />
```